# Memory leak using richTextCtrl and wxPython

Tags: python, wxpython, richtextctrl

I have a problem with memory leaks for a application using wxPython and wx.richtext.RichTextCtrl. The application resembles this one - *a simple digital clock on a window frame*. In order to keep the code clean I use a different module to update the "text module" (ModuleClock.py).

Anyone that knows why it behaves like this?

I have also tried:

- Replacing the richtext with a StaticText-object (wx.StaticText). **Result:** doesn't consume memory.
- No call at all to ModuleClock.py. **Result:** doesn't consume memory.
- *EDIT 1:* Using the commands rto.[Freeze()](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.Window.html#wx.Window.Freeze), rto.[Thaw()](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.Window.html#wx.Window.Thaw) and rto.[BeginSupressUndo()](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.richtext.RichTextCtrl.html#wx.richtext.RichTextCtrl.BeginSuppressUndo)
- *EDIT 2:* Moving the code from ModuleClock.py into Main.py (inside MainWindow.update method)

**Main.py**

```
import wx
import wx.richtext # as rt
import ModuleClock         #
from datetime import datetime
import os
import psutil

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    counter = 0
    lastcall = datetime.now()

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, size=(600, 500), pos=(0, 0))

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.panel.SetBackgroundColour('Black')

        self.clock = wx.richtext.RichTextCtrl(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, value="", size = (600,150), style=wx.VSCROLL | wx.HSCROLL | wx.NO_BORDER)
        self.clock.SetBackgroundColour('Black')

        self.timer = wx.Timer(self)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.update, self.timer)
        self.timer.Start(100)
        self.Show()

    def update(self, event):
        now = datetime.now()
        self.counter = self.counter + 1

        ModuleClock.update(self.clock)

        # Check memory use by process every 30 seconds
        if (now - self.lastcall).seconds > 30:
            process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
            print('memory use =', process.memory_info().rss/1000, 'kb')
            self.lastcall = now


app = wx.App(False)
frame = MainWindow(None)
app.MainLoop()
```

**ModuleClock.py**

```
from datetime import datetime


def update(rto):
    now = datetime.now()

    # default is black text
    rto.Clear()
    rto.BeginFontSize(16)
    rto.BeginTextColour("White")
    rto.WriteText(now.strftime("%A %d %B\n"))
    rto.BeginFontSize(36)
    rto.WriteText(now.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
```

**Command line output**

```
(venv) C:\Users\Danne\PycharmProjects\Leak>python Main.py
memory use = 31920.128 kb
memory use = 32657.408 kb
memory use = 33492.992 kb
memory use = 34144.256 kb
memory use = 34975.744 kb
memory use = 35545.088 kb
memory use = 36376.576 kb
[30 records removed]
memory use = 58028.032 kb
memory use = 58871.808 kb
memory use = 59404.288 kb
memory use = 60268.544 kb
memory use = 60801.024 kb
memory use = 61607.936 kb
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `ModuleClock` you are never cancelling the changes to text colour or the font size i.e. for every `Begin` there is an `End`
Change `ModuleClock` to:

```
from datetime import datetime


def update(rto):
    now = datetime.now()

    # default is black text
    rto.Clear()
    rto.BeginFontSize(16)
    rto.WriteText(now.strftime("%A %d %B\n"))
    rto.EndFontSize()
    rto.BeginFontSize(36)
    rto.WriteText(now.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
    rto.EndFontSize()
```

and add the line `self.clock.BeginTextColour("White")` after the `self.clock.SetBackgroundColour('Black')` in `Main.py`

Comment: Thanks man, that really did the trick. Been running the code for a couple of hours and no sign of memory build up.